# Как изменить заголовок окна при двойном клике мыши по ссылке (html)?

Tags: html

Вот написал код, не пойму почему не работает:

```
<html>
<title>
Задание 3 Вариант 16
</title>
  <script>
   function tit() {
document.title="Новый Заголовок"
   }
  </script>
<body>
<a href="" ondblclick="tit">ссылка</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Скорее всего нужно указывать функцию со скобками, я не сильно углублялся в инлайн объявлении. ```ondblclick="tit()"```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка с пустым адресом перезагружает страницу. До двойного клика дело не доходит. Нужно либо вписать `#` в `href`, либо добавлять предотвращение срабатывания ссылки через `click` (это отдельная тема).

И в атрибуте нужно вызывать функцию, а не просто указывать. Вот так должно работать:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>
Задание 3 Вариант 16
</title>
  <script>
   function tit() {
      document.title="Новый Заголовок"
   }
  </script>
<body>
<a href="#" ondblclick="tit()">ссылка</a>
</body>
</html>
```

А вообще, если ссылка служит только для клика, то это не ссылка. Используйте вместо неё `span` со стилизацией под ссылку, и вам не придётся сражаться с ней.